# batch file ping output to text file

Tags: file, batch-file, output, ping

```
@echo off

ping www.google.com > pinglog.txt

pause
```

I have this command but my problem is when you add ">" or ">>" the command prompt will not show what is going on on the background. Is there a way that everything will be copied after doing the ping?

I am aware of this code as well:

```
@echo off

ping www.google.com > pinglog.txt
type pinglog.txt

pause
```

but still, the screen stays blank as if nothing happens. I hope someone can help

Comment: I am not sure what you're trying to do, but try to delete/comment the `@echo off` line.

Comment: Find tee for Windows and its usage [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11239924/windows-batch-tee-command/21841567#21841567)

Comment: The second script should work to output after the ping is finished. Doing output to file and console while a program runs is not supported in batch.

Comment: It is working really fine but the problem is, I cannot see the ping as it happens. that's what I want to achieve. After the ping result while I can see the pings progress, will save all in a text file.

Answer (score 0):

Pipe to a Tee command.

```
ping www.google.com | cscript //nologo tee.vbs - t pinglog.txt
```

This is from filter.bat/vbs.

```
Set Arg = WScript.Arguments
set WshShell = createObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set Inp = WScript.Stdin
Set Outp = Wscript.Stdout
If LCase(Arg(0)) = "tee" or LCase(Arg(0)) = "t" then Tee

Sub Tee
    On Error Resume Next
    Set Fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set File = Fso.CreateTextFile(Arg(1), True)
    If err.number <> 0 then
        Outp.WriteLine "Error: " & err.number & " " & err.description & " from " & err.source
        err.clear
        wscript.exit
    End If
    Do Until Inp.AtEndOfStream
        Line=Inp.readline
        outp.writeline Line
        File.WriteLine Line
    Loop
End Sub
```

**Tee**

```
filter tee <Filename>
filter t <Filename>
```

Writes Stdin to a file and StdOut

**Example**

```
filter tee "%userprofile%\Desktop\winini.txt" < "%windir%\win.ini"
```

Comment: can't it be on just one bat file?

Comment: `wmic /append:c:\ping.txt PATH Win32_PingStatus where "address='127.0.0.1'" get responsetime,statuscode` type `wmic path Win32_PingStatus get /?` for help.